# Sorting multiple times in Aura lighting table gives me error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'rowIndex' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sort

Hiall! I am not sure whats causing this issue- I have a datatable with sort. It works fine the first time but when I click on Sort arrow a couple times, I start seeing this error in console and the sorting stops working.

```
 sortLocData : function(component, fieldName, sortDirection) {

    var data = component.get("v.searchLocationList");
    var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
    //sorts the rows based on the column header that's clicked
    if(fieldName == 'linkName'){
        data.sort(this.sortBy('Name', reverse));
    }else{
        data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
    }
    
    component.set("v.searchLocationList", data);
    

},

sortBy: function (field, reverse, primer) {
    var key = primer ?
        function(x) {return primer(x[field])} :
        function(x) {return x[field]};
    //checks if the two rows should switch places
    reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
    return function (a, b) {
        return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    }

},
```

[image]